# select multiple column from one table and insert into another as rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables users and emails:

```
USER
+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| id (PK)| email | email2 | email3 |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+

EMAIL
+---------+--------------+---------------+
| id (PK) | user_id (FK) | email_address | 
+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

I need to select emails from users table and insert them into emails table as rows.

Comment: show us what you tried so far and any problems that you are facing

Comment: You said "email2, email3, etc." - how many email columns is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your email table id has identity i would do it like this

```
INSERT INTO email (userid,email_address)
SELECT id, email  FROM user
UNION SELECT id, email2  FROM user
UNION SELECT id, email3 FROM user
```

Comment: Also, if you have null values in email2, email3 etc. I would set email as non-null (in fact you should make userid&emailaddress into a compound key). Like that you will not insert null emails in your new table.

Comment: @boisvert Good point. Having compound key will not only filter out null values it will also make sure redundancy are taken care of as well

Answer (score 0):

use union to do so.

```
insert into email values(
select user_id, email from user
union
select user_id, email1 from user
union
select user_id, email2 from user
union
select user_id, email2 from user
)
```